# How to connect to Blocto wallet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, blockchain, decentralized-applications

I am trying to create a dAPP using [Flow Blockchain](https://www.onflow.org/) using Flutter. I want to connect to the [Blocto wallet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.portto.blocto&hl=en_IN&gl=US) to approve transactions and get the account address as well. How can I do so in Flutter?

Answer (score -1):

You can.
Please take a look at this article. https://medium.com/@tickets.on.flow/how-to-call-blockchains-wallet-in-flutter-apps-633416720f23